# How to skip second line using a for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a code snippet, which prints the output by obtaining the number of lines from a shell script using for loop.

I want to skip the second line and print the remaining lines.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $output);       
    for ($i = 1; $i <sizeof($lines); $i++) 
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                $columns = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);
            }
```

Should I not be using *for* loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the number of line and make use of continue in php

```
for ($i = 1; $i <sizeof($lines); $i++) 
{
    if($i==2){ continue; }   
    echo '<tr>';
    $columns = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);
}
```

Comment: You beat me by few seconds

Comment: if you think my answer is correct, you can upvote the answer. Ha ha ha ... @FreedomPride , sorry

Comment: you deserve it :)